# Work done on spacewalks

Tags: iss, eva

What do most of the jobs done on spacewalks consist of? Changing small pieces on the ISS? Unbolting/unplugging a piece and putting the new one in?

Comment: That's kind of 2 different questions.  I suggest you edit the part about standards into a different question.  Getting a task list of EVAs is not too hard, but the other part might be.

Comment: I have reduced the question

Comment: Awesome! That one is definitely answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a brief summary of every ISS EVA ever (there have been almost 200 of them) at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_spacewalks).

If I were to attempt to summarize, there would be a few common categories.

1. Connecting cables and wires
2. Mounting devices such as antennae, Orbital Replacement Units (pumps, relay boxes, etc), cameras, et al
3. Working with the robotic arms to attach large elements to the station with bolts and remove their launch restraints
4. Various remove-and-replace repair jobs (including greasing bearings)